# VBA Direction API - Invalid Request Only through Code

Tags: vba, excel, google-maps-api-3

I'm from Brazil and sorry about my english but my error really driving me crazy!

I've already type a Code in VBA using this Directions API just for get the distance from A to B (in km).
Alright, I've talked to IT Security for allow my API Request and was permit and tested.

So today I set my macro to run perfectly and I discovered that my code return a INVALID_REQUEST, but more crazy about that is if I put the URL in the browser I get the response perfectly but when Excel try to run over coding, I get a INVALID_REQUEST from the XML return.

Look my code:

```
    Function gglDirectionsResponse(ByVal strStartLocation, ByVal strEndLocation, ByRef strTravelTime, ByRef strDistance, ByRef strInstructions, Optional ByRef strError = "") As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    ' Helper function to request and process XML generated by Google Maps.

    Dim strURL As String
    Dim objXMLHttp As Object
    Dim objDOMDocument As Object
    Dim nodeRoute As Object
    Dim lngDistance As Long

    Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set objDOMDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    strStartLocation = Replace(strStartLocation, " ", "+")
    strEndLocation = Replace(strEndLocation, " ", "+")

    strURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml" & _
                "?origin=" & strStartLocation & _
                "&destination=" & strEndLocation & _
                "&key=MY_API_KEY" & _
                "&sensor=false" & _
                "&units=" & strUnits

    'Send XML request
    With objXMLHttp
        .Open "GET", strURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
        .send
        objDOMDocument.LoadXML .responseText
    End With

    With objDOMDocument
        If .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK" Then
            'Get Distance
            lngDistance = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value").Text ' Retrieves distance in meters
            Select Case strUnits
                Case "imperial": strDistance = Round(lngDistance * 0.00062137, 1)  'Convert meters to miles
                Case "metric": strDistance = Round(lngDistance / 1000, 1) 'Convert meters to miles
            End Select

            'Get Travel Time
            strTravelTime = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/value").Text  'returns in seconds from google
            strTravelTime = formatGoogleTime(strTravelTime) 'converts seconds to hh:mm

            'Get Directions
            For Each nodeRoute In .SelectSingleNode("//route/leg").ChildNodes
                If nodeRoute.BaseName = "step" Then
                    strInstructions = strInstructions & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("html_instructions").Text & " - " & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("distance/text").Text & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next

            strInstructions = CleanHTML(strInstructions) 'Removes MetaTag information from HTML result to convert to plain text.

        Else
            strError = .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text
            GoTo errorHandler
        End If
    End With

    gglDirectionsResponse = True
    GoTo CleanExit

    errorHandler:
        If strError = "" Then strError = Err.Description
        strDistance = -1
        strTravelTime = "00:00"
        strInstructions = ""
        gglDirectionsResponse = False

    CleanExit:
        Set objDOMDocument = Nothing
        Set objXMLHttp = Nothing
End Function

Function getGoogleDistance(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the distance between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDistance = strDistance
Else
    getGoogleDistance = strError
End If

End Function
```

So, I just call the function gglDirectionsResponse sending, FROM and TO and the coding do the rest. As I said, I'd test and all works good, and now can't run. What I missing here guys?

The errorHandler is activate when the code try to run the specific line:

```
With objDOMDocument
        If .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK" Then
```

Here return INVALID_REQUEST.

Look the URL after loaded:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Porto+Nacional-TO&destination=Silvanópolis-TO,+Brasil&key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&units=metric](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Porto+Nacional-TO&destination=Silvan%C3%B3polis-TO,+Brasil&key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&units=metric)

Look the img from browser
[browser img, from api url in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxJ2w.jpg)

NOTE: I don't get macro or load or VBA code error, it's a errorHandler to validate the XML return, and the Return appear as invalid_request but browser load with success the same URL in the code.
Please please, somebody help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the request header to:

```
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT enter code here5.0)"
```

Don't know if it will work though..

Comment: variable strUnits does not seem to be initialized

Comment: You are right, i didn't notice that, i gues changing "&units=" & strUnits 
 to "&units=metric" would solve that.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I forgot to post ... my strUnits its a Constant on the module.

Const strUnits = "metric"

this code is the first line inside the module so I understand when it's a constant and its public one time inside the module this is already initialized.

But I'll try the both. just one sec!

Comment: So guys! I've tested and as I said, error against.

So for i divine light inside my head right now, I debbug de code and wrote:
.selectsinglenode("/").text

and for my surprise I could retrieve the error_message and get this:

"Invalid request. One of the input parameters contains a non-UTF-8 string"

How Can I discover this ducking parameter with a non-UTF-8 ? How fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in the answer before. The problem was found when I wrote the line:

```
.SelectSingleNode("/").text
```

*Obviously after .Send command.

this return for me that I send a invalid parameter that contain a non-utf-8 character.

So the code in XML "/" it's like the root structure, and with this, I could get the error_message to understand more correctly the error.

So as I said, I'm from Brazil and our cities have a lot of (', í,á,é,ó ...) so I'd test and get finally the correct status.

And now my problem is how to convert any character, but easily if we compare :D